# Function calculatebmi() is computing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          var x=0.02539;
        function calculatebmi()
        {
        var feet=document.bmiform.feet.value;
        var inches=document.bmiform.inches.value;
        var weight=document.bmiform1.weight.value;
        var height=(12*feet)+inches;
        height=height*x;
        var finalbmi=weight/(height*height);
        document.bmiform3.bmi.value=finalbmi;
        }
        </script>

<tr>
                    <td><h3>Enter your height</h3></td>
                    <td>
                        <form name="bmiform">
                        <input type="text" name="feet" size="5px"/>
                        FEET
                        <input type="text" name="inches" size="5px"/>
                        inches
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><h3>Enter your weight</h3></td>
                    <td>
                        <form name="bmiform1">
                        <input type="text" name="weight" size="5px"/>
                         KG
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                    <form name="bmiform3">
                    Your BMI:<input type="text" name="bmi"/>
<input class="button1" type="button" name="calculate"value="Calculate" onclick="calculatebmi()"/>

                </form>
                </td >

            </tr>
```

Why this function computing wrong value? i am accessing the forms correctly then why the answer is correct? and one thing also when i write calculate() instead of calculatebmi() in javascript,my calculate button do not produce any result? please get me through this i'm very new to html and javascript

Comment: were you using jsfiddle for this?

Comment: nope i'm not running it online.I'm using google chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic example of `number + str1 = str2`.

<strike>You also seem to be attempting to convert inches to metres but forgetting to convert pounds to kilograms.</strike>

```
// calculateBMI(kg, metres)
// calculateBMI(lb, feet, inches)
function calculateBMI() {
    var height,
        weight = arguments[0];
    if (arguments.length === 2) height = arguments[1];
    else {
        height = 12 * arguments[1] + arguments[2];
        weight *= 703.069006138;
    }
    return weight / (height * height);
}
document.bmiform3.bmi.value = calculateBMI(
    +document.bmiform1.weight.value, // notice unary + converting these to Number
    0.0254 * (12 * +document.bmiform.feet.value + +document.bmiform.inches.value)
);
```

Where `703.069006138` is *`1` lb in kg* over the square of *`1` inch in metres*, `0.453592 / (0.0254²)`

---

> please can u show me what i did wrong in my code

Your error is coming from this line (although the fix should be earlier in your code)

```
var height=(12*feet)+inches;
```

- Your value of `feet` is a *String*, but `12 * str` gives a *Number*, so we can ignore that
- Your value of `inches` is a *String*, so we have the *Number* `12 * feet`, call this `num`, and then we are adding the *String* `inches` (let's call this `str` to make things clear)

So what does `num + str` give us? Another *String*

Lets consider with values,

```
var feet = "5",
    inches = "10";
12 * feet; // 75
75 + inches; // "7510"
```

From here the rest of the calculation does not give you results as you expect

To fix this, convert your values to *Number* in advance of trying to use them. A quick and easy way to do this is with the unary `+` operator, `+"10"; // 10`

```
var feet = +document.bmiform.feet.value,
    inches = +document.bmiform.inches.value,
    weight = +document.bmiform1.weight.value;
```

---

You may also want to consider giving *ids* to your inputs, accessing via name in *JavaScript* is a bit messy

Comment: use r doing the same as i did except i only want BMI in kg/m2 please can u show me what i did wrong in my code

Comment: @sony your current code is attempting _lb/m²_ which makes no sense. You're also adding a string to a number, consider `1 + "2"; // "12"`

Comment: i donot understand what u r saying? i input the weight in kg, didn't i?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't look at your _HTML_.

Comment: please help me over here

Comment: can u please tell me why the feet is a string?

Comment: @sony because it's coming from an `<input>`. _values_ of `<input>`s are _Strings_.

Comment: thnks alot :) can u tell me some good resource where i can learn the basics of javascript ?

Comment: If you're having trouble with a specific object or native method, google search `mdn name`, e.g. if you're having trouble with `splice`ing, google  `mdn splice`. MDN is a good wiki for javascript. --- The main skill to learn when you want to debug _JavaScript_ is how to **use the console**. Methods like `console.log` will be your best friend and let you see exactly how your code is working. F12 will usually open the console, otherwise look [**here**](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)